# Rearranging the zoo::as.yearqtr() output

Tags: r, zoo

I know that I can call:

```
library(zoo)
Sys.Date()
CQ <- as.yearqtr(Sys.Date())
CQ
```

And get:

```
"2015-03-05"
"2015 Q1"
```

But I need my output to be:

```
"Q1-2015"
```

How can I convert CQ to be QX-YYYY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
format(CQ, 'Q%q-%Y')
#[1] "Q1-2015"
```

Comment: @user3731467 yes, it is

Comment: I was unaware that format worked like this... will be very helpful in the future!

Comment: @user3731467 The `%q` will give the numeric value and then we have to append `Q` to get the desired format

Comment: I'm surprised this is working... What is `%q`? I don't see it anywhere in the documentation and it doesn't work on a regular date.

Comment: @akrun is `%q` just zoo? or in base R as well?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please check `?format.yearqtr` from `zoo`

Comment: @user3731467 It is from `zoo`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar result using the base R. For example,

```
x <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 180L, by = "month") # Generate some dates vector
paste(quarters(x), as.POSIXlt(x)$year + 1900L, sep = "-")
## [1] "Q1-2015" "Q2-2015" "Q2-2015" "Q2-2015" "Q3-2015" "Q3-2015"
```